# Perform js when WP post updated

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to do a JavaScript job after a WordPress post has been updated (or created) and use the data of the just-updated post in the js (I need to send them to some API).
So far I know I have to enqueue script to wp-admin's edit.php:

**functions.php**

```
function wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script( $hook ) {
    if ( 'edit.php' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tha_adminjobs', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js-fanky/adminjobs.js', array(), '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script' );
```

Now I can have an action on update-button click:

**js-fanky/adminjobs.js**

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".editor-post-publish-button", function(){
     console.log("hi");
});
```

But how do I access the data? I can see they get returned from post.php?post={someid} - i see it in XHR calls list:

[image: xhr calls]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-api-fetch/) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320483/uncaught-typeerror-wp-apifetch-is-not-a-function/320488).

I modified the script enqueuing to use a dependency "wp-api-fetch"

```
function wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script( $hook ) {
    if ( $hook != 'post.php' && $hook !='post-new.php' ) { //fixed wrong url here too
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'tha_adminjobs', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js-fanky/adminjobs.js', , array( 'wp-api-fetch' ), '1.0' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script' );
```

and then I used a "middleware" to get to the JSON from wp rest api, which is on the screenshot in the question. It gets the JSON right before it uses it to populate the admin form fields.

```
var apiFetch=null;

$(document).on("click", ".editor-post-publish-button", function(){
    if(apiFetch==null){ //the listener is not set yet. Setting it after the first publish click, otherwise it would fire also on editor load
            var apiFetch=wp.apiFetch;
            apiFetch.use( ( options, next ) => {
                const result = next( options );
                result.then( () => {
                    if(result._v.status=="publish"){ //to get only the post, not other api answers
                        //play with result JSON here
                        console.log(result._v); 
                    }
                } );
                return result;
            } );
    }
});
```